# rmarkdown::render in parallel

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, r-package

I have the R package, one of its function - produce report. In the inst/markdown I have a template rep.rmd. In the package function ProduceReport() I have this code:

```
  render.file <-"rep.Rmd"
  render.file <- system.file(TEMPLATES.PATH, render.file, package=getPackageName())
  render.dir <- dirname(render.file)
  pdf.file <- "example.pdf"
  rmarkdown::render(render.file , quiet = FALSE, output_format = "pdf_document")
```

It works, but during the execution markdown produces directories temp files

> rep_cache, rep_files

I would like to test this report generating function in parallel (when .rmd files run with different inputs and produce different reports). 
**My first question, is it possible to run same .rmd file with different inputs in parallel?**

I guess that temp directories should have unique names to avoid writing to the same files. I found arguments

> intermediates_dir = , knit_root_dir =

in the **rmarkdown::render()** function. But when I try to define this parameters with created dir, pandoc produces errors (and rep_cache, rep_files directories are still in their places).

Please, any advice.

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/17bc21af55392f23f012f57bb2fda51c) gist by [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr)

Answer (score 3):

As [@Kevin_Arseneau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1543551/kevin-arseneau) pointed, see:

```
library(doParallel)

rpts <- list(list(out="one.html", params=list(some_var="One")),
             list(out="two.html", params=list(some_var="Two")),
             list(out="three.html", params=list(some_var="Three")),
             list(out="four.html", params=list(some_var="Four")))

do_rpt <- function(r) {

  require(rmarkdown)

  tf <- tempfile()
  dir.create(tf)

  rmarkdown::render(input="tstrpt.Rmd",
                    output_file=r$out,
                    intermediates_dir=tf,
                    params=r$params,
                    quiet=TRUE)
  unlink(tf)
  
}

registerDoParallel(cores=3)

foreach(r=rpts, .combine=c) %dopar% do_rpt(r)
```

Sample file:

```
---
title: Test Report
output: html_document
params:
  some_var: "default"
  some_date: !r as.Date("2015-01-01")
---

Report for `r params$some_var` run on `r params$some_date`
```

[Source: hrbrmstr](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/17bc21af55392f23f012f57bb2fda51c)

Answer (score 0):

Specify different `output_file`s.  Then the cache and temp dirs get named after the output file.